# mscomm compatibility with modems

Tags: vba, modem

I'm using a rather simple script that dial automaticaly a set of numbers. It works correctly on my computer (a laptop with integrated modem) but on my colleague computer (to whom the script is designed in the first place) it works for the first number, and then it doesn't work at all (the modem won't dial any number, and doesn't display any error), unless we reboot the computer. What setting or mscomm property could explain this behaviour? I suspect maybe I close the speaker at the end of the call and do not open it in the start of the new one...

```
    Dim CancelFlag As Integer
Dim RingCount As Integer
Dim raccrocherFlag As Integer

' Démarrage
Private Sub btnStart_Click()
' On Error GoTo Gest_err
    For Each numtel In Sheets("ListeTRS").Range("b2:b10000")
            ' Si bouton Cancel a été pressé, on arrête le script
            If CancelFlag = 1 Then
                UserForm1.Hide
                Exit Sub
            End If


            valNumtel = Val(numtel)
            If valNumtel = 0 Then
                MsgBox "Fin de fichier."
                Exit Sub
            Else
                ActiveSheet.Range("A" & numtel.Row).Select
                If Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:2")) Then Dial numtel, numtel.Row
            End If
    Next
End Sub


Private Sub Dial(Number, Indice)
Dim DialString As String
Dim FromModem As String
Dim dummy As Integer

' AT is the Hayes compatible ATTENTION command and is required to send commands to the modem.
' DT means "Dial Tone." The Dial command uses touch tones, as opposed to pulse (DP = Dial Pulse).
' Numbers is the phone number being dialed.
' A semicolon tells the modem to return to command mode after dialing (important).
' A carriage return, vbCr, is required when sending commands to the modem.

' Concatene 0 avant le numéro
dialnumber = "0" & Number

DialString = "ATDT" + dialnumber + ";" + vbCr

' Communications port settings.
' A faire > detecter le port ou le demander à l'usager?
Dim comPort As Integer
comPort = 3
MSComm1.CommPort = comPort
MSComm1.Settings = "9600,N,8,1"
RingCount = 0

On Error Resume Next
    ' Ouvrir le port s'il est fermé
    If (MSComm1.PortOpen = False) Then
        MSComm1.PortOpen = True
    End If


    If Err Then
        MsgBox "COM" & comPort & " n'est pas disponible. Changer la propriété à un autre port."
        Exit Sub
    End If

' Flush the input buffer.
MSComm1.InBufferCount = 0

' Dial the number.
        Sheets("ListeTRS").Range("D" & Indice).Value = "Appel en cours du " & dialnumber & " § " & Now
        MSComm1.Output = DialString


         ' On attend 10 seconde puis on lis les infos disponible dans le tampon du modem
        If Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:20")) Then
        FromModem = FromModem + MSComm1.Input
        End If


            ' Raccrocher
            MSComm1.Output = "ATH" + vbCr



' Disconnect the modem.
MSComm1.Output = "ATH" + vbCr

' Close the port.
MSComm1.PortOpen = False
End Sub

Private Sub cmdStop_Click()
CancelFlag = 1
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
'Setting InputLen to 0 tells MSComm to read the entire contents of the
'input buffer when the Input property is used.
MSComm1.InputLen = 0
End Sub



Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Excel.Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim Number As String

' Get the number to dial.
Number = Target.Value
If Number = "" Then Exit Sub

' Dial the selected phone number.
Dial (Number)
End Sub
```

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work any more" - does it give an error, or exactly what happens? Can you paste in the script here? We need more details if you want us to be able to help!

Comment: Of course, I've added more details and the script itself. A few of the comments are in French, sorry.

Comment: Have you stepped through the script with a debugger on your colleague's machine?

Comment: Try introducing a delay between ATH and closing the port, the port close wont wait for ATH to complete

Comment: You can also send whatever command it is to activate terminal echo ATE  ? and monitor your conversation with the device for errors using portmon from sysinternals

Comment: Tried that, didn't work, BUT when launching the script step by step (F8), it works, so it must be a delay somewhere that prevent the script from working.

Comment: About your second comments, I don't know what your talking about :)

Comment: I really don't get it, I can go through the script as fast as as I want and it will work, but it won't in normal mode.

Answer (score 1):

Had this one myself in a similar situation.

You have to be explicit with the object,in this case Excel. Assuming you have named xlApp as the excel.aplication then try this:

```
For Each numtel In xlapp.Sheets("ListeTRS").Range("b2:b10000")
```

and:

```
If valNumtel = 0 Then
                MsgBox "Fin de fichier."
                Exit Sub
            Else
                xlApp.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & numtel.Row).Select
                If xlApp.Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:2")) Then Dial numtel, numtel.Row
            End If
```